# Хранения изображений на Firebase

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

При создании приложения возник вопрос по поводу хранения изображений на сервере.
Мне необходимо хранить аватарки пользователь, чтобы их можно было и загружать, и принимать с севера.
Авторизация была разработана на Firebase ( Java ). Можно ли в консоли, в таблице пользователей сохранять и выкачивать изображения для приложений? А ссылки url? Тогда где хранить изображения? Какой хостинг? И что лучше хранить на прямую в Firebase( если есть такая возможность) или на отдельном хостинге? Если второе, то какие библиотеки и инструменты есть для этого и не будут ли конфликтовать между собой Firebase и другой хостинг? 
Я только углубляюсь в эту тему, и поэтому очень много мне не известно. Если есть возможность, можете дополнительно к своему ответу отметить ссылки,книги,видео, что еще дополнительно надо знать. Поподробнее рассказать про весь этот движ :)
Заранее благодарю вас за ответ, не дайте пропасть юному программисту :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать чтобы загружаемые изображения хранились в Firebase Storage, а также рекомендую ознакомиться с https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images
Если данные ваших пользователей хранятся в Firebase Database, то Вы можете сделать в таблице пользователей ячейку где будет указан путь хранения ваших изображений, это может быть хостинг Firebase или внешний.
В Firebase Вы можете хранить любую информацию, а также синхронизировать.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ
Тобишь на Firebase есть возможность хранить изображения для каждого пользователя по ключу?
Пользуюсь readData

Comment: После установки Resize Images, когда загружаешь изображение у него есть определенный токен. Вы также можете в ячейке пользователя указывать путь изображения, даже если оно хранится на внешнем хостинге.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,друг